# Weird uncaught syntax error, missing ")" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, web, fetch

I'm trying to use this code: `var html = (await (await fetch(url)).text());` when I use it in the chrome dev console it works perfectly. The problem is when I try using it in a html file in the  tag it spits out the "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" error. It seems like a dumb question but I've been at it for a long time and can't seem to figure it out!

Here is the rest of the code:

```
function get_yt_data(link) { 
    var url = "api.codetabs.com/v1/proxy?quest=" + link; 
    var html = (await (await fetch(url)).text()); // html as text var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html'); 

    script = doc.getElementsByTagName('script')[27].text.replace('window["ytInitialData"]', 'data'); 

    eval(script); 

    return [data.header.c4TabbedHeaderRenderer.title, data.header.c4TabbedHeaderRenderer.avatar.thumbnails.slice(-1)[0].url]; 
};
```

Comment: This code has no problem. You should write here other lines of your code. The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @Eryk - please put (and properly format it) to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't put in inside an `async function`, and `await` is no keyword but treated as an identifier. The code is just as syntactically invalid as `(a (b c(d)).text())`.

In the devtools console on the other hand, Chrome implements top-level `await`.